# How to check if list item exists using item URL

Tags: 2007, list, development

At the moment I am trying to delete list item file using this code,

```
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPListItem Item = web.GetListItem(ListURL + fileName);
                        Item.Delete();
                    }
                }
            });
```

but I need to do validations if item exists or not, I know I can iterate list items but is there any easy way of checking if item exists using URL of item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SPWeb.GetFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476063%28v=office.12%29.aspx) followed by [SPFile.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.exists%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile(fullUrl);
if(file.Exists)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (SPListItem listItem in list.Items)
{
  string s= listItem.Name;
  SPFolderCollection Foldcoll = list.RootFolder.SubFolders;
  foreach (SPFolder RootFold in Foldcoll)
  {
      var file = listItem.Web.GetFile(listItem.UniqueId);
      if (file.Exists)
      {
          file.delete();                                 
      }     
  }
}
```